# LoadRunner Runs fine when recording, errors on playback

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I have a LoadRunner script that logs on to a secure website, navigates to a page, deletes the current file, uploads the replacement file, saves it, and logs out.

When I Record in LoadRunner, I navigate through the website, delete the file, upload the file, save it and exit no problem. LoadRunner dutifully creates the script for me. It asks me to Correlate the parameters, and I do.

When I Playback the script that I just created, it logs into the website, navigates to the page, deletes the current file, and then hangs on the upload of the file with a MERR-26612 error.

I wish I had more expertise in LoadRunner to call upon for help, but there's nobody here with it. I've just been left with this to work on by myself.

How do I even go about determining what the problem is with LoadRunner, and then how do I determine how to fix it in the LoadRunner script?

Thanks for any and all help. I'm in the dark here.......

Comment: I understand your frustration but much like other software, LoadRunner requires some training before you can use it for complex scenarios (beyond open a page press a button).

Comment: You should try seeking help on the official LR forum here http://www.hpe.com/forum/lrpc

Comment: Do not assume that all dynamic elements are addresses by the automagical correlation engine.  This is why several different models of manual correlation are covered in training, before the introduction of automatic correlation.   Record it twice:  Examine the recordings for differences that highlight correlation candidates.